# How to create a custom iterator in Julia 1.0?

Tags: iterator, julia

I have this structure in Julia 1.0:

```
mutable struct Metadata
    id::Int64
    res_id::Int64
end
```

So that I can create an array of these, where the `id` is always incremented by one, but the `res_id` is only sometimes incremented, like so:

```
data = [
    Metadata(1, 1),
    Metadata(2, 1),
    Metadata(3, 1),
    Metadata(4, 2),
    Metadata(5, 2),
    Metadata(6, 2),
...]
```

What I want to do is be able to iterate over this Array, but get blocks based on the `res_id` (all the data with `res_id` 1, then 2, etc). The desired behavior would be something like this:

```
for res in iter_res(data)
    println(res)
end

julia>
[Metadata(1, 1), Metadata(2, 1), Metadata(3, 1)]
[Metadata(4, 2), Metadata(5, 2), Metadata(6, 2)]
```

How do I do this in Julia 1.0, considering that I also need to normally iterate over the array to get element by element?

Answer (score 2):

In Julia 1+, this should be done by implementing `Base.iterate(::YourType)` to get the starting iteration and `Base.iterate(::YourType, state)` for other iterations based of some `state`. These methods should return `nothing` when done, otherwise, `(result, state)` tuple.

Iterating on YourType with

```
for i in x
    # stuff
end
```

is then a shorthand for writing

```
it = iterate(x)
while it !== nothing
    i, state = it
    # stuff
    it = iterate(x, state)
end
```

See the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/) for details.

Comment: I meant to post this answer in another question, but I feel it is still relevant here, so I will leave it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a [Generator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Generator-Expressions-1) of [filter](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.filter)s like this:

```
julia> mutable struct Metadata
           id::Int64
           res_id::Int64
       end

julia> data = [
           Metadata(1, 1),
           Metadata(2, 1),
           Metadata(3, 1),
           Metadata(4, 2),
           Metadata(5, 2),
           Metadata(6, 2),
       ];

julia> for res in (filter(x -> x.res_id == i, data) for i in 1:2)
           println(res)
       end
Metadata[Metadata(1, 1), Metadata(2, 1), Metadata(3, 1)]
Metadata[Metadata(4, 2), Metadata(5, 2), Metadata(6, 2)]
```

Comment: But in this case I wouldn't know that there are only two types of res_id, to choose when you say `for i in 1:2`. How do I find out how many unique types of res_id there are in the array. And what if they have "gaps", like 1, 3, 4, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

From the names of your variables it seems you are collecting the data from some computational process. Normally you use `DataFrame` for that purpose.

```
using DataFrames
data = DataFrame(id=[1,2,3,4,5,6],res_id=[1,1,1,2,2,2])
for group in groupby(data,:res_id)
    println(group)
end
```

This yields:

```
3×2 SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}}
│ Row │ id    │ res_id │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 1      │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 1      │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 1      │
3×2 SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}}
│ Row │ id    │ res_id │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64  │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 4     │ 2      │
│ 2   │ 5     │ 2      │
│ 3   │ 6     │ 2      │
```

This is also more convenient for further processing of results.

Comment: Thanks, this seems useful. But I don't know that the incorporation of the types `SubDataFrame` are going to ease my problem. Still, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You can always do this: `for group in DataFrame.(groupby(data,:res_id))` and then you have a `DataFrame`s

Answer (score 0):

How I eventually handled the problem:

```
function iter(data::Vector{Metadata}; property::Symbol = :res_id)

    #GET UNIQUE VALUES FOR THIS PROPERTY
    up = Vector{Any}()
    for s in data
        getproperty(s, property) in up ? nothing : push!(up, getproperty(s, property))
    end

    #GROUP ELEMENTS BASED ON THE UNIQUE VALUES FOR THIS PROPERTY
    f = Vector{Vector{Metadata}}()
    idx::Int64 = 1
    cmp::Any = up[idx]
    push!(f, Vector{Metadata}())
    for s in data
        if getproperty(s, property) == cmp
            push!(f[idx], s)
        else
            push!(f, Vector{Metadata}())
            idx += 1
            cmp = up[idx]
            push!(f[idx], s)
        end
    end
    return f
end
```

This allows me to accommodate "skipped" res_id's (like jumping from 1 to 3, etc) and even group the Metadata objects by other future characteristics other than res_id, such as Strings, or types other than Int64's. Works, although it probably isn't very efficient.

You can then iterate over the Vector{Metadata} this way:

```
for r in iter(rs)
    println(res)
end
```

Comment: You should get the unique values like this `unique(getfield.(data,:res_id))`. Never ever search using full scan over an Array (unless it has just 3 or elements). Rather use a `Set`

Comment: And your code will not work with `data = [Metadata(1, 1),Metadata(2, 3),Metadata(3, 1)]`.  You should have a single loop and use `Dict{Int64,Vector{MetaData}}`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need a `groupBy` function. Here is an implement for reference, in Haskell

```
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```